# All my blocks are gone. Even the block menu entry is gone

Tags: 6, blocks

Anyone know what I might have done? I found a few things about hook_block being implemented in template.php causing this, but I don't implement hook_block at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Context module. Once I disabled it my blocks came back.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a module and theme with the same name, this will happen (regardless if you do/don't have hook_block in either of theme).